# should there be an actual ld directory in /usr/bin/?

Tags: linux, matlab, libstdc++

I am trying to install a simulator in Matlab. The code used for installation uses the mex command but when I run the function, i get the error:

Error using mex
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Error in compile_mex (line 62)
mex('-outdir',libdir,CListO{i});

There is no separate directory in /usr/bin/ called "ld". I am not sure where my error lies. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ld is the GNU linker. It's an executable file, not a directory.

Comment: thank you. I did not know that. Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: The error means the linker is failing to find a particular library in it's search path, specifically libstdc++. During the install process you need to make sure that this library is in the linker's search path. You haven't posted what commands you're trying to run or the operating system you're on, so that's about all I can say about resolving the error.